# Mysql Deadlock on insert and update

Tags: mysql

I am running into a dead lock during moderate-to-high load situations. Here are the details.

MySQL-5.5.21-55

Engine: InnoDB

**Table: Order**

```
# Field, Type, Null, Key, Default, Extra
id, bigint(20) unsigned, NO, PRI, , auto_increment
sno, varchar(32), NO, MUL, ,
misc1, int, NO, , 0,
```

**Table: OrderItem**

```
# Field, Type, Null, Key, Default, Extra
id, bigint(20) unsigned, NO, PRI, , auto_increment
order_id, bigint(20), YES, MUL, , 
f1, varchar(50), YES, , , 
f2, varchar(100), YES, , , 
misc2, int, NO, , 0,
```

- **Order**.sno is unique
- **OrderItem**.order_id is not defined as foreign key but used as foreign key in the application
- **Order** has *one-to-many* relation with **OrderItem**
- **OrderItem**.order_id + **OrderItem**.f1 + **OrderItem**.f2 is unique

**Usecase:**

- Whenever any record in **Order** or **OrderItem** needs to be updated, I want to invalidate the old records (or delete) and insert new ones.
- It may so happen that earlier, one record in **Order** (e.g order1) has 3 records in **OrderItem** (e.g orderItem1, orderItem2, orderItem3). But now I want to have it as order1->orderItem1, orderItem4, orderItem5 or entirely new set. This is the reason why i want to invalidate the old records all together and insert new ones as finding out what is changed in **OrderItem** is complicated.

Multiple threads will be doing this operation; but they will work on different record sets. I'm operating on 25 **Order** s at a time

**What I tried:**

- Insert into **Order**; on duplicate key update **Order** and delete all children from **OrderItem** and insert the **OrderItem** s.
- Have another column called *is_active* in **Order** and mark all the records for the same *sno* as 0 and insert the new records in **Order**; insert new children into **OrderItem**.
- Delete from **Order** for the given sno; delete from **OrderItem** for the same sno.Insert into both the tables freshly.

All the above approaches resulted in deat lock, some or the other time.
No other thread or process is working on these tables.

**Observation:**

Went through the following links

- [InnoDB record level locks](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-record-level-locks.html)
- [InnoDB locks set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locks-set.html)

and found that updating/deleting multiple records causes MySQL to obtain *Next Key* locks at REPEATABLE_READ isolation level (which is the default). In my opinion this causes the problem.

Appreciate if you can provide some direction on solving this.

Comment: Locks only block other connections, you can't have a deadlock between operations on the same database connection.

Comment: how does "new order" action trigger...? a simple http request?

Comment: @Barmar Connections are not shared by threads.

Comment: to be 100% sure, so you KEEP the order record, delete all chile orderitem record, then instead new child orderitem?

Comment: @JackyCheng that is what i did in approach#1

Comment: if your system neds to take in real time request, may I ask what do you need to send out as the immediate response? is it just a "record updated!" notice? I've updated my answer, would that help?

Comment: Kind of. Earlier, i didnt want to complicate. We have a message consumer for SwiftMQ. That will trigger the call to insert/update Order and OrderItems. At the end of the operation it sends SUCCESS or FAILED response to the queue so that it can be retried in case of failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, (perhaps a workaround, in-line with @JackyCheng's suggestion), Im,

- Inserting into **Order** table (multiple records at a time); **no update on duplicate key**
- Inserting into **OrderItem** table (multiple records at a time);
- Select all **Order**.ids that are to be updated
- Mark the identified **Order** (ids) as inactive one-by-one ***(this is the key part as it uses index key lock and not the next key lock)***

Overall the transaction execution time remains below 30ms for 25 Orders.

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't mention it, I'll give it a try, have you tried "FOR UPDATE" ?

set connection auto commit to false.

at the beginning of program, use this to lock all relevent data.

```
SELECT o.* , oi.* 
FROM order o 
INNER JOIN orderitem oi ON (o.id=oi.order_id) 
WHERE o.id = <order id to update> 
FOR UPDATE;
```

then you can do whatever you want to those entries.
then commit.

*EDIT:* I think the root cause of the problem is multi threading (obviously), I was thinking if it's better if you remove that element from the equation.

imagine a system where you have multiple receiver that receives request. Those receiver will only do something like:

```
//select to check if there is a existing record(no need to lock), if no, return fail as response
SELECT o.* , oi.* 
FROM order o 
INNER JOIN orderitem oi ON (o.id=oi.order_id) 
WHERE o.sno = <sno to update>;

insert into request_buffer (request_id, sno, new_order_item,create_date .......) 
values
(1, abc , orderitem1......);
//return success after inserting buffer.
```

where you have a seperate single thread program that pools this table and handle those buffer entries.

In that case it would seperate the multithread element from the DB updateing process. I am not sure about the amount of incoming request but I think if you handle a few more request per cycle/query then the preformance wouldn't be THAT significantly different?

Comment: I had this as the last resort; i.e., performing delete/update operation one record at a time. The moment i use range in where clause, i.e., IN clause, it uses NEXT KEY locks, which causes dead lock.

Comment: @PragalathanM modified the second method a bit. added checking on receiver

Comment: the problem is load. we wanted to have multiple servers processing these records.Records are in the order of a million per hour. So either we have to have multiple threads on same server, or multiple servers.

Comment: Right,then I have nothing except maybe suggest you to look into MySQL Cluster. Even that I am not sure would it help or not. Good luck finding a solution.